# What is the highest number of badges that a single post can earn?

Tags: discussion, statistics

I'm wondering what the maximum number of badges a post (whether question or answer) could theoretically earn is. I'm thinking that for a user who self-answered their first question six months after they asked it, and it got 100 upvotes, they could get nine badges:

- Enlightened
- Guru
- Nice Answer
- Good Answer
- Great Answer
- Revival
- Necromancer
- Self-Learner
- Teacher

For a question, if they asked their first question, which sat with low activity for a while, then they offered and rewarded a bounty on it and accepted an answered, and finally it got a bunch of views, upvotes, and favorites, they could get the following 13 badges:

- Benefactor
- Favorite Question
- Stellar Question
- Nice Question
- Good Question
- Great Question
- Popular Question
- Notable Question
- Famous Question
- Promoter
- Scholar
- Student
- Tumbleweed

At first glance it seems like this is the highest number of badges a single post could get. Is this correct?

I'd also be interested to know which post has actually earned the most badges, as I'm sure the above scenarios have probably never happened.

Comment: Peer Pressure could also be a possibility. In theory, you could delete the post at -3, then edit it to be awesome, undelete it and go on to earn the nicer badges.

Comment: You can also earn the publicity badges, once for each post you share.

Comment: @Yannis And Disciplined with the same reasoning. Once the post has reached 3, you can delete it, earn the badge, undelete it and continue to receive upvotes after that.

Comment: Additionally, this one extra answer can be all you need to cross a threshold for a tag badge. Since you can have up to five tags per post, those are another five potential badges.

Comment: An answer could also cause the generalist badge to be earned. Oh, and Reversal is missing.

Comment: Could you get both the Disciplined and the Peer Pressure badges on one question? I.e. could you delete when it got to -3, edit, undelete, and then when it gets to +3, delete again? And then of course, undelete and earn all the other badges.

Comment: I was also wondering about the Tag badges and Generalist badges. They're not tied to a specific answer (at least from the UI perspective), so I wonder if there would be any way to figure out which answer actually caused the badge to be earned.

Comment: You definitely could earn the Generalist badge and any tag badge from such an answer if it is the final one needed to push your tally over the edge, along with Mortarboard, Epic, or Legendary. Additionally, you could use the question or answer as your first opportunity to perform a roll-back, earning you the Cleanup badge.

Comment: @TylerH Oh definitely, but my question is more how would you calculate that? As in, how would you be able to determine, say, for a prolific user who earned the generalist badge 3 years ago, which upvote on which post made them finally cross the threshold?

Comment: @JoeKennedy I'm not sure we could determine that unless the user answered or asked 1 question per day or fewer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've created a couple of queries to try and answer this question, but a lot of badges are impossible (or incredibly difficult) to determine using the Stack Exchange Data Explorer. For greater simplicity I'll limit the badges I consider to those that are directly tied to a post when viewing the help page for that badge. (As an example, the help page for [Nice Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/20/nice-question).)

## Questions

For questions, I was only able to determine the following badges:

- Nice Question
- Good Question
- Great Question
- Popular Question
- Notable Question
- Famous Question
- Favorite Question
- Stellar Question
- Promoter
- Editor (was the question the first post the user edited)
- Cleanup (was the question the first post the user rolled back)

Question badges I can't/don't know how to/don't want to determine:

- Benefactor
- Tumbleweed
- Student
- Scholar

The following *might* have posts tied to them, but since I don't have enough reputation to view the flag queue or deleted posts, I'm not sure if the help pages look different for users who can.

- Citizen Patrol
- Disciplined
- Peer Pressure

I'm also going to exclude the Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badges from calculations, for a few reasons. First, because there is no possible way to calculate them using the Data Explorer, as share information isn't in there. Second, they can be earned (in theory) at infinite number times for a single question. Every single one of SO's 4.2 million and counting users could share a link to a question, and if each is clicked on by 1000 different IP addresses, the question would earn 4.2 million Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badges.

### The Query & Results

**The query:** [Which questions have earned the most badges?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/397952/which-questions-have-earned-the-most-badges)

**The results:** Of the eleven badges my query calculates for, only one question has earned all eleven badges.

[Auto Scale TextView Text to Fit within Bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5033012/2856441), asked by [Nathan Fig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150020/nathan-fig)

This question didn't earn any of the badges I didn't calculate in my query, as Nathan never awarded the bounty, he had previously asked questions, and hasn't shared the question heavily. Let's step down to the 7 questions that earned 10 of the 11 badges the query calculates.

- [What are the real-world strengths and weaknesses of the many frameworks based on backbone.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10847852/2856441), asked by [danikoren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197370/danikoren)
- [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81584/2856441), asked by [husayt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15461/husayt)
- [Creating a left-arrow button (like UINavigationBar's "back" style) on a UIToolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/227078/2856441), asked by [marco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30480/marco)
- [What is the best way to stop people hacking the PHP-based highscore table of a Flash game](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73947/2856441), asked by [iain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11911/iain)
- [Singletons vs. Application Context in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3826905/2856441), asked by [mschonaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368544/mschonaker)
- [Creating an API for mobile applications - Authentication and Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3963877/2856441), asked by [jsuggs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389999/jsuggs)
- [Should IBOutlets be strong or weak under ARC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7678469/2856441), asked by [hypercrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/713558/hypercrypt)

All of these questions earned the eight "XYZ Question" badges and then two out of three of the remaining ones.

The spread:

```
| Asker      | Promoter | Editor | Cleanup |
+------------+----------+--------+---------+
| danikoren  |     X    |    X   |         |
| husayt     |          |    X   |    X    |
| marco      |     X    |    X   |         |
| iain       |          |    X   |    X    |
| mschonaker |     X    |    X   |         |
| jsuggs     |     X    |    X   |         |
| hypercrypt |     X    |        |    X    |
+------------+----------+--------+---------+
```

As for the badges not included in the query, how do these questions stack up? None of them earned Tumbleweed badge but they earned some combination of the three remaining ones.

```
| Asker      | Benefactor | Student | Scholar | New Total | 
+------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+
| danikoren  |     X      |         |    X    |     12    |
| husayt     |            |    X    |         |     11    |
| marco      |     X      |    X    |    X    |     13    |
| iain       |            |         |         |     10    |
| mschonaker |     X      |         |         |     11    |
| jsuggs     |            |         |         |     10    |
| hypercrypt |     X      |    X    |    X    |     13    |
+------------+------------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

So hypercrypt's and marco's answers are now the answers to beat, at 13, and since a question that earned 9 of the 11 calculated can only earn at most 4 of badges that weren't calculated, **it's safe to conclude that 13 is the highest number of non-sharing badges that a question has *directly* earned**.

## Answers

For answers, I was able to calculate the following badges:

- Nice Answer
- Good Answer
- Great Answer
- Guru
- Enlightened
- Reversal
- Populist
- Necromancer
- Editor
- Cleanup

I was unable to/didn't calculate the following:

- Revival
- Self-Learner
- Teacher

And same with questions, I was unsure if I could/should calculate the delete and flag badges:

- Citizen Patrol
- Disciplined
- Peer Pressure

### The Query & Results

**The query:** [Which answers have earned the most badges?](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/397359/which-answers-have-earned-the-most-badges)

**The results:** Of the ten badges I calculated, the most any one answer earned was seven, which was kind of surprising. But six answers earned that many.

- [How do I set up NSZombieEnabled in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4917557/2856441), answer by [Jano](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412916/jano)
- [Is it possible to set UIView border properties from interface builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15839914/2856441), answer by [Rich86man](https://stackoverflow.com/users/640618/rich86man)
- [Check if an array contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8574392/2856441), answer by [patrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1107661/patrik)
- [Xcode Product -> Archive disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18791703/2856441), answer by [wiseindy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1135804/wiseindy)
- [The target … overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26077106/2856441), answer by [Ankish Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2478235/ankish-jain)
- [Why is jquery's .ajax() method not sending my session cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5422323/2856441), answer by [flu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/601386/flu)

But which of them earned which badges? Well, all of them earned Nice Answer, Good Answer, Great Answer, and Necromancer. As for the other ones,

```
| Answer by   | Guru | Enlightened | Reversal | Populist | Editor | Cleanup |
+-------------+------+-------------+----------+----------+--------+---------+
| Jano        |   X  |      X      |          |          |    X   |         |
| Rich86man   |   X  |      X      |          |          |        |    X    |
| patrik      |      |             |          |     X    |    X   |    X    |
| wiseindy    |   X  |      X      |          |          |        |    X    |
| Ankish Jain |   X  |             |          |          |    X   |    X    |
| flu         |   X  |      X      |          |          |    X   |         |
+-------------+------+-------------+----------+----------+--------+---------+
```

So if we include the badges that the query doesn't, which answer has earned the most?

```
| Answer by   | Revival | Self-Learner | Teacher | New Total |
+-------------+---------+--------------+---------+-----------+
| Jano        |    X    |              |         |     8     |
| Rich86man   |         |              |         |     7     |
| patrik      |         |              |    X    |     8     |
| wiseindy    |    X    |              |    X    |     9     |
| Ankish Jain |         |              |         |     7     |
| flu         |    X    |              |    X    |     9     |
+-------------+---------+--------------+---------+-----------+
```

So unless one of 88 answers with 6 of the badges the query calculated has all three of the answer badges it didn't calculate (anyone interested in finding that out?), I proclaim the "Badgyest Answer" to be a tie between wiseindy's answer on "Xcode Product -> Archive disabled" and flu's answer on "Why is jquery's .ajax() method not sending my session cookie?". Even if there's an answer with six of the calculated badges and all three of the non-calculated badges, **it seems like nine is the highest number of badges an answer has *directly* earned.**